# I accidentally created a local branch named origin/foo. Now what?

Tags: git, branch

I have a remote branch named `foo`, that is not tracked in the current client.

I did `git checkout -b origin/foo`, and this created a local branch named `origin/foo`. This looks bad, since up until now all my local branches didn't have a `origin/` prefix.

I tried to delete this local branch by running `git branch -d origin/foo`, but it complained that the branch is not fully merged. I'm afraid that if I'll force it using `-D`, it will actually delete the remote branch.

How do I clean up this mess?

Comment: In the meantime, I renamed it to bad_foo until I figure out what to do.

Comment: Now that you have renamed it, do you actually still have a problem?

Comment: @Mat - now that you mention it, I just tried to delete bad_foo and it worked. Hurrah!

Comment: Note that it would be safe to delete this branch. Remote branch deletion only happens via push.

Comment: @MichaelMior - yes, but I do intend to push this repository later on.

Comment: That's fine since `origin/foo` will have no associated remote tracking branch. Anyway, you can't delete remote branches unless you specify the `-f` option to `git push`.

Comment: @MichaelMior - still, what if I sometime in the future `push -f`? It's better to be sure to delete just the local branch.

Comment: @ripper234 This still wouldn't delete the remote branch. The syntax for `git push` is `git push remote branch`, so `git push origin/foo` would result in an error and `git push origin origin/foo` would create a branch named `origin/foo` on the remote `origin`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6192/discussion-between-ripper234-and-michael-mior)

Answer (score 37):

Resolved by renaming the branch and then deleting it.

```
git branch -m origin/foo bad_foo
git branch -d bad_foo
```

Comment: lol, note to self: make sure you're not in the branch you're deleting...

Answer (score 4):

ripper234's answer is correct however for those who might overlook the missing "git", it's:

```
git branch -m origin/foo bad_foo
git branch -d bad_foo
```

I would've commented but don't have enough "reputation" to comment yet